# can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myapplication.MessageClass

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myapplication.MessageClass

MessageClass.class code this.

```
public class MessageClass {
    String userId,messages,messageId;
    long timestamp;

    public MessageClass(String userId, String messages, long timestamp) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public MessageClass(String userId, String messages) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    public MessageClass(){

    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

ChatActivity.java

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView imageView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageView backArrow,video,call,menus,send_btn,AttachFile,Emoji;
    EditText EnterMessage;
    TextView username;
    FirebaseDatabase database;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.chat_pro_pic);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView2);
        backArrow=findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        video=findViewById(R.id.video_call);
        call=findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
        menus=findViewById(R.id.menu_btn);
        send_btn=findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        AttachFile=findViewById(R.id.files_btn);
        Emoji=findViewById(R.id.emoji_bar);
        EnterMessage=findViewById(R.id.type_msg);
        username=findViewById(R.id.chat_username);
        FirebaseAuth mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        final String senderId= mAuth.getUid();
        String receiveId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String profilePic= getIntent().getStringExtra("profilePic");

        username.setText(name);
        Picasso.get().load(profilePic).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(imageView);

        backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ChatActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        final ArrayList<MessageClass> messageClasses =new ArrayList<>();
        final chatAdapter chatAdapter=new chatAdapter(messageClasses,this,receiveId);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final String senderMe =senderId+receiveId;
        final String receiveMe =receiveId+senderId;

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderMe)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        messageClasses.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            MessageClass msg =snapshot1.getValue(MessageClass.class);
                            msg.setMessageId(snapshot1.getKey());
                            messageClasses.add(msg);
                        }
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

        send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message = EnterMessage.getText().toString();
                final MessageClass classes= new MessageClass(senderId,message);
                classes.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
                EnterMessage.setText(message);

                database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderMe)
                        .setValue(classes).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        database.getReference().child("chats")
                                .child(receiveMe)
                                .push()
                                .setValue(classes).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this code i have to face some error while i am running this app. I have input something in edittext that text save into firebase realtime data base, but don't show in mobile application `ChatActivity` and app has been crash.

Export JSON file from firebase database.

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3" : {
      "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Abc",
      "password" : "123456"
    }
  },
  "chats" : {
    "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3" : {
      "messages" : "hiii",
      "timestamp" : 1632570537312,
      "userId" : "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this fragment of your code:

```
database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderMe)
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            messageClasses.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                MessageClass msg =snapshot1.getValue(MessageClass.class);
                msg.setMessageId(snapshot1.getKey());
                messageClasses.add(msg);
            }
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

You attach a listener to `/chats/$user`, which means the `snapshot` will contain this data:

```
"PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3" : {
  "messages" : "hiii",
  "timestamp" : 1632570537312,
  "userId" : "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3"
}
```

Then within `onDataChange` you loop over `snapshot.getChildren`, so `snapshot1` will be `"messages": "hiii"`, `"timestamp" : 1632570537312` and `"userId" : "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3"` in turn.

And then you try to read data from `snapshot1` with `snapshot1.getValue(MessageClass.class)`. This won't work, because `messages` (and the other properties in turn) are **not** a full message.

---

Your code is made to work on a data structure like this:

```
"PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3" : { //  user ID
  "-LMSDjlfsdfhkjsdf90318": { //  message ID
    "messages" : "hiii",
    "timestamp" : 1632570537312,
    "userId" : "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3"
  },
  "-LMTsdfh23sad9023343": { //  message ID
    "messages" : "hello again",
    "timestamp" : 1632570537342,
    "userId" : "PWGD0vsRhfd83tqM1ClwvwqJIRD3"
  },

}
```

But you're missing that level `message ID` in your current data structure. When you add that level, it will work.

Alternatively, you can remove the `for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){` loop and read the single message you current have from `snapshot` with `snapshot.getValue(MessageClass.class)`.